# Как правильно подключить bootstrap-datetimepicker?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap

Подключаю все необходимое и вставляю `html` из примера на офф. сайте:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.7" data-semver="3.3.7" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker-standalone.css" />
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker-standalone.min.css" />

    <script data-require="jquery@3.1.1" data-semver="3.1.1" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/locale/en-au.js"></script>
    <script data-require="bootstrap@3.3.7" data-semver="3.3.7" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="MomentJS@2.10.0" data-semver="2.10.0" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker1">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" />
              <span class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

[Пример на планкере](https://plnkr.co/edit/c5X8abj4bHlvn2rs5guk?p=preview)

В итоге получаю обычный `input` с картинкой календаря. В консоле никаких ошибок. В чем может быть дело ?

Comment: Даже после исправления, предложенного ниже, в исходном коде чего-то не хватает, т.к. отображаемый виджет выглядит криво (особенно часть по работе с часами).

Comment: Пропущены теги `rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"` при включении css - это основная причина, почему виджет выглядит криво в некоторых (возможно , во всех) браузерах...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В `JavaScript` необходимо прописать код, который задействует `datetimepicker`:

```
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
```

Пример рабочего `datetimepicker` для Вашего кода:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.7" data-semver="3.3.7" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker-standalone.css" />
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker-standalone.min.css" />

  <script data-require="jquery@3.1.1" data-semver="3.1.1" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="bootstrap@3.3.7" data-semver="3.3.7" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="MomentJS@2.10.0" data-semver="2.10.0" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker1">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" />
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```